# Python Flask: What happens in the background and how to call some function only once?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, python-requests

I have been using Flask for long time but apparently blindly. The app that I am running is hosted in App Engine and it is working fine. Today I came across a situation that made me think about how does Flask and App Engine work. Here's structure of my app:
**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def f1():
.
.
.
def f2():
.
.
.
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There are many parts of the app that are irreverent to my question. I understand that whenever there is a GET/POST request f1() is called. So when I deploy the app in App Engine what exactly happens in the background? Suppose I want to call f2() only once, to retrieve some data from API and use that data in f1(). Can I just call it in main() and save it into a global variable? Or how do I go about that? I am trying to optimize database and API calls to make app faster so that is the reason for calling f2() only once.
Would appreciate some clarification or reference to relevant resource to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
@app.route('/', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def f1():
```

Your function has a decorator `@app.route`. This binds your function `f1`. You can have n number of decorator to your function. If you want to call `f2` function you can call at the end of your script and you can use it as global variable.

```
a = ''

@app.route('/', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def f1():
    global a
.
.
.
def f2():
   global a
.
.
.

f2()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My suggestion is to add a decorator to `f2` so that you can call that function again if need in future to change the global data.

```
@app.route('/some_secret_address', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def f2():
    global a
```

Comment: This is a very useful practice that I use in my apps.

Comment: I will have an in-depth look on using decorator to the functions. Usually, I create a new file with some functions and then import them and use them. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: That's a good practice. It will help you easy debugging. Try Flask Blueprint.